# How to disable b-tooltip auto position placement Bootstrap-Vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I have a tooltip, and I want it to always be at the top and center, it won't change when resizing even though there's not enough space at the top. I want the tooltip to overflow to the outside. But it changes position by itself when there is not enough space

Link sanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-bootstrap-vue-8vjtl?file=/src/App.vue

```
   <div style="background: #ccc">
       <div id="tooltip_1" style="background: #fff"><div>
       <b-tooltip :target="tooltip_1" placement="top" fallback-placement="flip"   triggers="click blur">
         Text demodemo
       </b-tooltip>
    <div>
```

Right now it's like this:
[image]

But what I want:
[image]

Looks like it's related to `fallback-placement` but I don't know how to turn it disable.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Did you try this `<div id="tooltip_1" v-b-tooltip.hover.top="'Text demodemo'" style="background: #fff"><div>`. For more details please refer https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/directives/tooltip/#positioning

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty thank you! But I want to style and add the html to the tooltip, I added a sandbox demo link https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-bootstrap-vue-8vjtl?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. [Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-bootstrap-vue-forked-ondts?file=/src/App.vue)

Approach 1: Need to add `boundary="document"`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="box">
        <div
          class="item"
          id="tooltip-target-1"
          :style="{ width: sizeWidth + 'px' }"
        >
          Click me
          <b-tooltip target="tooltip-target-1" triggers="click" placement="top"
          boundary="document">
            <span class="bold">I want it</span><br />
            <span>break the line</span><br />
            <span class="yellow">and custom style</span>
          </b-tooltip>
        </div>
        <button @click="zooOut">Zoom</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

Approach 2:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="box">
        <div
          class="item"
          v-b-tooltip.click.top.html="toolTipData"
          id="tooltip-target-1"
        >
          Click me
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      toolTipData: {
        title: `<span class="bold">I want it</span><br /><span>break the line</span><br /><span class="yellow">and custom style</span>`,
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you!  but i have one more question, how can the tooltip move always in the middle of the element when the element changes width? please help me
https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-bootstrap-vue-forked-1028s?file=/src/App.vue:659-667

Comment: In your sandbox it always opens in the middle of the element, After increasing the width just click the `Click Me` button again. Once you notice that and if this helps mark this as answer so that it will be helpful to others too.

Comment: I don't want to click again, I want it to be automatic, because this is a simple example, but I am working on a system with hundreds of tooltips that cannot be clicked to change each one. But you answered my main question, so I'll mark it as helpful.

Comment: I don't think we can achieve it automatically, because the position of the tooltip is determined at the time of render.

Comment: If use `b-tooltip` then that works, but it can't show the position at the top
https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-bootstrap-vue-8vjtl?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: I think there is a way to `trigger` it, but since it uses Vuejs I don't know how to `trigger` it

Comment: see if this helps https://buefy.org/documentation/tooltip/#custom-content

Comment: I got the solution, add `boundary="document"` to the `b-tooltip` tag

Comment: OMG!!!! it solved all my problems even the wrap `overflow: auto`  awesome, thank you so much!